# Is it possible to transfer my save to the Steam version, and vice versa?

Tags: little-racers-street

[*Little Racers STREET* is now available on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/262690/), and I've redeemed my Steam code from Desura.  While I'll most likely keep my DRM-Free copy around so I can play with my Dad, the Steam one sounds like it has some added perks, namely some exclusive new vehicles.

I don't really want to have to start over though.  Is there some way I can copy my save from the Desura version to Steam?  And the other way around?  One thing I'm a little worried about is that if the Steam edition has extra vehicles, the saves may not be compatible anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DRM Free version save file is in

> %USERNAME%\Documents\SavedGames\LittleRacersStreet\LRStreetSave\Player1

and the Steam save file is in

> Steam\userdata\30528937\262690\remote

I tried disabling cloud, I tried finishing a race and then replacing the save file, I even tried making it read only, but every time you load the game, it gets defaulted to new game save.

Conclusion: You have to start over, because the save files are incompatible. Unless you find a way to stop steam from resetting the save file.